# Geo2D format not conserved when concatenating NetCDF files with ncecat in nco

Tags: bash, shell, netcdf, nco

I have some monthly NetCDF files that I would like to concatenate into one to use some of the movie making abilities of Panoply. The original files do not have a `time` variable, but NCO seems to get easily around it using

```
ncecat -u time file1.nc file2.nc file3.nc All_files.nc
```

as described in [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/nco/discussion/9830/thread/31e466d4/).
However, when I open the new file, the variables that were Geo2D in the original files have turned into plain 2D variables, and I can't use some of the overlays offered by Panoply such as country borders.

Is this

1) normal and there is no way around it, or

2) am I doing something wrong, or

3) is there something that should be added to the original files to conserve the info from the Geo2D format?

Comment: This is a great question and if you learn anything that we can incorporate upstream into NCO please let us know.